# One-to-many association in sails.js creation failure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

Sails.js application fails to create one-to-many relationship in mongo db:

According to official [Documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many) I created two linked one-to-many entities, Post-Likes. I located them in api/models folder and defined as follows:

**Like.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    post: {
      model: 'post',
      required: true
    }
}
```

**Post.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    likes: {
      collection: 'like',
      via: 'post'
    },
    user: {
      model: 'user'
    }
  }
}
```

And I populate likes for the post with a following statement on the page:

```js
  const posts = await Post.find({user: id})
    .sort('createdAt DESC')
    .populate('user')
    .populate('likes');
```

After I run sails.js app with command `sails lift --drop` and load the page with code above I receive the following error message in console:

> error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:   UsageError: Invalid
>   populate(s). Details:   Could not populate `like`.  There is no
>   attribute named `like` defined in this model.
>
> ```
> at Object.module.exports [as user/profile] (/Users/new/Developer/ios/social/web_social/api/controllers/user/profile.js:8:30)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> ```

I checked mongo db instance and I cannot see any empty or null `like` attribute for `post` entity:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to make your model name initCap. like below

```
    module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    post: {
      model: 'Post',
      required: true
    }
}
```